# Python condition syntax irregularity

Tags: python, syntax

This is valid:

```py
def not_none(some_variable) -> bool:
    return some_variable != None
```

And this is also valid:

```py
def not_none(some_variable) -> bool:
    return some_variable is not None
```

Why is this invalid?

```py
def not_none(some_variable) -> bool:
    return some_variable not None
```

I would think that it means the same as the previous one.
Is there any reason it is not allowed?

Comment: Just fyi if it is not clear: `is` is used to check identity. There is only one `None` object in Python which is why it is general best practice to use `is` or `is not` to check whether a name is `None`.

Comment: Note that `a is not b` is not `a is (not b)` but instead is syntactic sugar for `not (a is b)`

Comment: I understand that. I was assuming that the `is` and `not` in `is not` were separate operators. It turns out they are one complete keyword.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a *[unary `not`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#not)* (takes *one* operand and negates it), and an [`is not`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#is) operator (optimised negation of `is` operator); however, there's no *binary `not`* operator (taking two operands).

Answer (score 1):

`not` is a *unary* operator, it only accepts a single argument (whatever is on its right). Compare that with `is not` and `!=` which are *binary* operators that each accept two arguments.

This is a problem because with just `not`, you essentially have

```
return (someVariable) (not None)
```

But that doesn't make sense. `someVariable` is just floating there before the call to `not`. It doesn't understand what you're intending, so you get an error.

Comment: Is the role of `not` in `not` and `is not` different? Are they different keywords? Or are both `not` the same?

Comment: @Jaideep They're different operators. `is not` is *one* operator.

Comment: @deceze Okayyy. I see. That means I was using an entirely different operator.

Comment: @JaideepShekhar Yes, it looks like a special case of negation of `is`, but it's really a whole different operator that just reuses keywords.